# clean method not called in modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

As written in the title, the form gets validated whatever happens, I don't understand why are my clean and clean_ methods are not called. Used forms for quite some time but here I am puzzled on what I am forgetting. 
Thanks

```
simplified forms.py

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["workcity", "post_address", "billing_address", "country", "phone"]

        def clean(self):
                #not called
                cleaned_data = super().clean()
                billing_address = cleaned_data.get('billing_address')
                post_address= cleaned_data.get('post_adress')

                if not billing_address == post_address:
                    do some raising validation error
       
        def clean_workcity(self, *args, **kwargs): 
            #not called
            workcity= self.cleaned_data.get("workcity")
            if xxx:
               do some raising validation error



            return workcity
```

```
simplified  views.py

def profileform(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile created successfully')
            return redirect('profile')
        else :
            handle errors 
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
   

    return render(request, "CORE/home.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: **Typo**: You've put your methods inside the `Meta` class, they need to be in the form class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdul, that's why one doesn't work on sundays... You commented on my question instead of answering directly I think so I cannot accept it (no ticking logo to click on). You want to copy paste in an answer format so I can accept it?